# Text extraction from html code using regex

Tags: c#, html, regex

```html
<time datetime="2014-10-18T19:30:00-0600">Saturday 18 October 2014</time>
```

I need to extract the date "Saturday 18 October 2014". I know i should use something like:

```
MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(downloadBandData, @"<time daytime=""\s*(.+?)\s*</time>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

However, i don't know the exact expression that i should use.

Answer (score 2):

For future parsing of HTML, a tool other than regex is recommended. However, you can use the following..

```
Match m = Regex.Match(downloadBandData, @"<time[^>]*>([^<]+)</time>");
if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value); //=> "Saturday 18 October 2014"
```

The reason your regular expression does not match is because you try to match `daytime` instead of "datetime" and you were not matching the content between the double quotes `" ... "` or the closing bracket `>`

The correct representation of your regular expression should of looked like this:

```
@"<time datetime=""[^""]*"">\s*(.+?)\s*</time>"
```